# Linear and Integer programming materials

Tags: linear-programming, reference-request, integer-programming

I was wondering if you could refer me to some online video/text resources to learn linear and integer programming. I am intending to work in the field of data science. I greatly appreciate your kind help. Have a good evening!

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Have you checked the questions with [tag:reference-request] or even [tag:online-resources] tags? You can find many great textbook references there.

Comment: I have checked those tags but did not see anything specific to my query!

Comment: Related: See the *Linear Programming* and *Integer Programming* sections of [this answer on Introduction to OR](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/870/123). The books listed there can be accessed if you have an institutional account. Otherwise, there are a variety of online resources [available on Coursera](https://www.google.com/search?q=linear+and+integer+programming+coursera&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB812GB812&oq=linear+and+integer+programming+cour&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0.5360j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire You voted to close the reference https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-are-good-reference-books-for-introduction-to-operations-research/870#870 which you just provided in your comment. That seems non-optimal. I think that the referenced link is a good one, and should be re-opened.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I closed it precisely due to the question's vagueness - there are just too many references for the *entirety* of OR. That is not to say the quality of your answer is the same as that of the question. Your answer provides some good links to various topics, and therefore I will not delete the question, although I support its closure.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire It's a community Wiki answer, although I provided a significant portion of the content. That it has a reasonable answer is evidence that it was not too broad or vague.  Now a good answer is "discredited" by virtue of the question being closed, which sends a signal that it is not meritorious.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Your second statement does not follow as any broad question can be reasonably "answered" partially, which is what you have provided. The status of a question is independent on the quality of an answer (there are plenty of examples on Math.SE with closed questions and "meritorious" answers to them). To avoid clogging the comments section, please consider the [OR chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94323/operations-research) as a potential alternative for discussion.

Answer (score 11):

Since you mentioned videos, I would suggest checking [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) and [edX](https://www.edx.org/) for free MOOCs (such as the [Deterministic Optimization](https://www.edx.org/course/deterministic-optimization-0) course on edX or the [Discrete Optimization](https://www.coursera.org/learn/discrete-optimization) course on Coursera). The Coursera site in particular has a nice search engine that makes finding courses easy. I have not done any of the optimization courses there, but I have done a couple of the analytics courses, and liked them greatly.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the online courses that *prubin* mentioned, I can recommend the [Convex Optimization](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/CVX101/Winter2014/about) online course from Stanford University with the following features:

- The course is very helpful and free.
- The textbook is also freely available on the website.
- There are quizzes in the MOOC which help your learning process.