# Does there exist an aggregation of videos on optimization?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, online-resources

Is there a website or otherwise maintained list of talks regarding mathematical optimization? This would be a big help for the community it seems. I'm most interested in those relating to integer programming.

Comment: Can be related: [Linear and Integer programming materials](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/linear-and-integer-programming-materials/)

Comment: Based on the answers below, you might want to clarify whether you are asking for introductory, tutorial-type videos, or advanced, research-type videos.

Answer (score 10):

There are these great introductory lectures on coursera (not sure if that qualifies for your question as they are not research talks):

[Discrete Optimization](https://www.coursera.org/learn/discrete-optimization), [Solving Algorithms](https://www.coursera.org/learn/solving-algorithms-discrete-optimization), [Basic Modeling](https://www.coursera.org/learn/basic-modeling) and [Advanced Modeling](https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-modeling).

If you are into research seminars / current topics, Aleksandr M. Kazachkov has compiled an interesting [list of online seminars on optimization](https://akazachk.github.io/seminars.html).

Answer (score 10):

In terms of conferences, the [Egon Balas Symposium](https://www.cmu.edu/tepper/faculty-and-research/seminars-and-conferences/egon-balas-symposium/program.html) in 2019 contained numerous talks on mathematical optimization. For integer programming specifically, it includes

- the Geometric Firefighter Routing Problem (Cid de Souza)
- the Graphical Traveling Salesman Problem (Neil Simonetti).

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, the 2th part of [my talk at Devoxx Morocco](https://youtu.be/dW_b_n737TU?t=4796), explains Tabu Search, Simulated Annealing and other (meta)heuristics.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of online courses: [Mathematical Optimization](https://www.ima.umn.edu/2015-2016/ND8.1-12.16#schedule) and [Optimization: Principles and algorithms](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjC9MQ2I7a5ZdWh31gFvC1A/playlists),

Answer (score 4):

Check out Gurobi's materials: https://www.gurobi.com/resources/

Answer (score 3):

You can find an introductory course of **Convex Optimization** from *Stanford University* taught by Professor Stephen Boyd, in this [link](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/CVX101/Winter2014/course/).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following link from the Simons Institute (they had a program on [bridging continuous and discrete optimization in 2017](https://simons.berkeley.edu/programs/optimization2017)).

Also the Hausdorff Institute had a [trimester on combinatorial optimization in 2015](https://www.him.uni-bonn.de/programs/past-programs/past-trimester-programs/combinatorial-optimization-2015/recorded-talks/).