# Suggested Resources for Non-Linear Optimization

Tags: optimization, reference-request, nonlinear-programming

I recently completed an undergraduate course in Linear Programming and Operations Research. I am willing to look into advanced concepts and Non-Linear Optimization algorithms and also, their method of implementation using a programming language/toolbox. I would be glad if I am guided towards specific resources.

Answer (score 11):

There are plenty of courses and books out there.
For convex optimization I'd take a look into Boyd's & Vandenberghe's lecture which also has a [good accompanying script](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf).
The [lecture/book](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/Lect_ModConvOpt.pdf) from Nemirovsky & Ben-Tal is also very good.
If you are looking into algorithms that can be used for general (non-convex) problems, you might want for example look into the [nonlinear programming course at MIT by Bertsekas](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-252j-nonlinear-programming-spring-2003/lecture-notes/).
There are more advanced topics like optimization with differential equations or the interplay of optimization methods and machine/deep learning. But I'd start out with the more general ones before going into the more advanced ones.

As a personal note, I advise you to also look at the discrete part of OR, i.e. the Mixed-Integer Programming world which is a nice advanced topic which you could explore coming from linear programming. The interplay of mixed-integer and nonlinear problems is even more advanced (and interesting).

Comment: Also see references at https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-are-good-reference-books-for-introduction-to-operations-research/870#870 , particularly J. Nocedal, S. Wright. "Numerical Optimization". Note my comment on Nemirovsky & Ben-Tal: "Very advanced mathematically".  And why in the heck is that linked topic closed? Give me a break.

Comment: If you want to solve convex nonlinear models consulting https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html might be worthwhile.

Comment: +1 @ErlingMOSEK . I included that on the Wiki answer at the link in my comment above. I referenced the log-sum-inv modeling solution there a couple of days ago to answer a CVX Forum question.