# VRP book recommendations

Tags: reference-request, vehicle-routing, logistics

I am looking for a book recommendation on the VRP and variants.  I am encountering VRP-like problems more and more in my work and would appreciate a reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is one book to know about VRPs, it is:

["Vehicle Routing: Problems, Methods, and Applications, Second Edition" (Paolo Toth and Daniele Vigo, 2014)](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611973594)

Comment: I took the liberty pf adding a new category "Vehicle Routing Problems" and placing this reference there at "What are good reference books for introduction to operations research?" https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-are-good-reference-books-for-introduction-to-operations-research