# Book to learn metaheuristics

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, heuristics, metaheuristics, local-search

I want to learn about metaheuristics and start building one to solve combinatorial optimization which is pretty hard to solve. I am looking for book recommendation or any learning experience to learn this topic. Python preferred for the programming language but i'm open to anything and not limited to.

Answer (score 10):

The most famous book on metaheuristics is probably the *Handbook of Metaheuristics*:

> Michel Gendreau and Jean-Yves Potvin. 2010. Handbook of Metaheuristics (2nd. ed.). Springer Publishing Company, Incorporated.

which is freely available [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-1665-5). It includes a large range of metaheuristics such as *Simulated Annealing*, *Tabu-Search*, *Variable Neighborhood Search* or *Genetic Algorithms*.

Code wise I would suggest you to start with a problem where you find enough resources such as the TSP and a metaheuristic that you think is easy to implement (personally I started with Simulated Annealing). If you do not have experience with any other programming language, Python is a good choice, because it is fast to learn. However, starting with another language such as C++ might also be a good choice, because it will teach you the basics of programming and is more performant.

Comment: Julia is also a rising star these days with the "promise" of the convenience of Python and speed of C++.

Comment: i did learn c++ language but given the popularity of python, i choose to learn python.

Comment: Nice. But not freely available if not affiliated with eligible institution. You should consider adding this to https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-are-good-reference-books-for-introduction-to-operations-research .

Comment: is there a book in which they discuss about the theory first and then implemented with the code? I really looking for this resources material.

Answer (score 2):

Two good (free) books are:

- Essentials of Metaheuristics: [https://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/](https://cs.gmu.edu/%7Esean/book/metaheuristics/)
- Clever Algorithms: https://github.com/clever-algorithms/CleverAlgorithms

If you want to try Julia, this is a good start point: https://jmejia8.github.io/Metaheuristics.jl/stable/