# Where can I find resources to learn mathematical modelling for real life operation research problems like combinatorial optimization?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, cplex, combinatorial-optimization, books

I find it hard to form math models for real life operations research problems, how can I learn this? Any books, tutorials available?

Comment: I recommend checking the other posts that have the books tag.

Comment: The NPTEL lecture series on operations research: https://nptel.ac.in/courses/112106134/ has a number of examples. The solver ILOG CPLEX is shipped with a number of coding examples. You can find the corresponding mathematical model online.

Comment: Resources introduced in [this relevant question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/117/recommended-books-materials-for-practical-applications-of-operations-research-in) are all recommended.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you may get many different answers but the one I have used for 20+ years is

**Model Building in Mathematical Programming** by H.P.Williams

Many models are in the OPL CPLEX examples and some other [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/model-building-oplcplex-alex-fleischer/)

Comment: All 29 of these examples from the Williams book are in SAS [here](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=ormpex&docsetTarget=titlepage.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en).

Answer (score 2):

*A Course in Combinatorial Optimization*, by Alexander Schrijver

[https://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/dict.pdf](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Elex/files/dict.pdf)