# Operations Research self-study resources for beginners

Tags: books

I am interested in OR, and I am looking for self-study resources targetted towards beginners.  If it helps, I am looking for something similar to the ["Schaum's Outline of Operations Research"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Schaum_s_Outline_of_Operations_Research/16sK1voVookC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover), or a self-study resource where the theory is accompanied by many solved examples.

Comment: Also see this related question: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/869/2477

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE, really the question that @dhasson mentioned is a good answer to your question.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/where-can-i-find-resources-to-learn-mathematical-modelling-for-real-life-operati/3870#3870

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The book "Model Building in Mathematical Programming" by H. Paul Williams is a great resource. The first part is a practical approach to methods and the second part is all problems with description, formulation and solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few online courses (MOOCs) and other free video resources. You'll need to do a search to find them all.